# CORS on asp.net core web api doesn't work after deploy on IIS

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis

I'm developing a net core webapi with an angular front end. When i was debugging everything works fine, now that i had deploying the web abi on IIS I can't make it works, it gives me CORS errors: `"...No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."`

here is the code to enable CORS on web api:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
    services.AddCors();

...
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
...
    app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());
```

I have try different solution i've found in this and other site, nothing seems to work

should i add some kind of header in my angular app?
Could the problem be with IIS?

Comment: Did you check the headers you actually receive? Look for other errors in your browser's console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem:
I had enabled "Basic Authentication" on IIS because I mistakenly thought it was the right things to do.

I found that IIS "Basic authentication" is different from what I had implemented (I created a custom "BasicAuthenticationHandler" that read headers e validate users)

The problem was that IIS (or Angular, or Chrome, i don't know) instead of returning error "401 unauthorized" gave me CORS error even if "Anonymous authentication" was enabled (it's mandatory to disable all other authentications).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this.

In your Startup.cs file

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
           services.AddCors(cfg =>
           {
                cfg.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
                {
                     policy.WithOrigins("list of origins to allow here")
                     .AllowAnyHeader()
                     .AllowAnyMethod()
                     .AllowCredentials()
                     .SetIsOriginAllowed((_) => true)
                     .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
                });
           });


services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                     options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                     options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                     options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
                })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
      }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
      {
         app.UseCors();
         app.UseMvc(routes =>
           {
                routes.MapRoute(
                     name: "default",
                     template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{tag?}");
           });
      }
```

Do make sure Cors is called before the call to MVC.

I hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: I don't use Mvc, i use
`services.AddControllers();`
and 
`app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });`
If i try tu use your code it gives me this error: _'JsonOptions' does not contains a definition for 'SerializerSettings'_ and of course it doesn't work (it works only when debugging)

Comment: simply get rid of the the AddMvc and UseMvc in your case.

Comment: already done it, I copied the "services" part and "app.UseCors();", still doesn't work as i written in the first comment

Comment: OK, could you try going through this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I have try everything, nothing seems to work, i even create a method with `[AllowAnonymous]`, but it gaves me error 400. Maybe there is some IIS configuration errors (i use this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-3.1)