ASP.NET Core 8 Web API CORS problems with Angular 18 frontend
I got a CORS problem I simply can't get my head around, hope someone can help me.
My frontend is Angular 18, the backend is an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with a few endpoints, where not all works for some reason.
Everything works as I expect on localhost, login etc. is butter smooth.
But as soon as I publish the Web API, only some of my endpoints work.

https://tools.brokenholiday.online/audio-converter

The endpoint for this component works as I expect and all is good:


https://tools.brokenholiday.online/login

Endpoint handling the login request returns

Access to fetch at 'https://api.brokenholiday.online/authenticate/login' from origin 'https://tools.brokenholiday.online' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

My Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<JwtSecurityTokenHandlerWrapper>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options => {
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(JwtAuthorizeFilter));
});

builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
        builder => builder
            .WithOrigins("https://*.brokenholiday.online", "http://localhost:4200")
            .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials());
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

app.MapControllers();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.Run();


does the 1st request (the one that works) include credentials?

@browsermator no it does not contain any credentials, full open endpoint.
login endpoint doesn't require auth but it sends login credentials. Does this mean you go an idea what I'm missing? :D

well the browser rules are different for credentialed requests... so you can't wildcard origins (not sure if that applies to subdomain wildcard) and you can't have non-https.  The other thing that could be an issue is app.UseCors should be placed after app.UseHttpsRedirection and after any routing (which might mean after app.MapControllers();...  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#middleware-order

@browsermator I've tried placing the useCors after Map and UseHttps. Plus removed the wildcard and my localhost entry. Sadly still the same outcome

browser doesn't seem to think there's any response to OPTIONS request there.  Might just try installing CORS module:  https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module  (or checking IIS for OPTIONS verb support)  If there's any kind of reverse proxy might need to put CORS responses there?  You should also try putting app.UseMiddleware(); last.

I've tried putting it last, same outcome. I'll try to reach out to my hosting provider. If anyone else got an idea please shoot. And thanks for the inputs! :)

Maybe this is a better link for checking order of useCors:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#uc1

tried the new order as well and moved it to AddDefaultPolicy as the link shown. Still same outcome. This is so strange to me my other endpoints work.

best case is always to keep everything same-site/same-domain.  Then you wouldn't need to use CORS header responses at all.  You can, instead, just put your endpoints at your-domain/api/.... and serve front end from just your-domain.

Besides avoiding wildcard, cors issue occurs when publishing usually relates to the server settings. One similar case would be this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60059332/cors-on-asp-net-core-web-api-doesnt-work-after-deploy-on-iis . Also check if your proxy settings correct.

With .Net 8 Microsoft changed the SPA proxy so that the proxy would be implemented on the front-end rather than the back-end. (actually earlier, but with .Net 8 it is the default)
The problem with this is that CORS errors can be introduced because the browser sees the front-end running at say https://localhost:4200
but the backend might be running at https://localhost:7010.
For instance, if you implement authentication in your backend, using the standard Authentication middleware, for OAuth, the Challenge request tells the browser to redirect to the authentication, and return to the backend redirect_uri (for instance https://localhost:7010/signin-oidc).
This is where the CORS error gets introduced, because the port numbers make the two different localhost origins, and the browser will block because :4200 and :7010 are different origin domains.
The older SPA proxying in .Net Core 3 and available (I think even in .Net 8 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions, puts the proxy in the back-end, but the templates with Visual Studio no longer support this.
Microsoft did create their YARP (reverse proxy) which someone implemented as a AspNetCore.SpaYarp - which moves the proxy to the back-end, and I have been using that to support middleware OAuth authentication, and it has been working well.
You can find it at https://github.com/berhir/AspNetCore.SpaYarp
and install it from NuGet.
